# How to find Charles proxy URL?

Tags: windows, http

I am trying to use [Charles Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/using-charles/web-interface/) web interface to -hopefully- be able to control it from the command line. I am starting Charles with headeless mode:

```
> Charles -headless
```

As per the documentation it is just simple as going to a web page "http://control.charles/". It seems to be working just fine from IE, but for some reason I cannot seems to get it working from a cmd window:

```
> ping control.charles
```

this results in an error.

Answer (score 1):

Afer struggling, I finally found out that the following works (from an rxvt shell):

```
$ export http_proxy=http://localhost:8888
$ wget control.charles
```

HTH